# unpack structured binary data with python

Tags: python, struct

I very often use the `struct` package to parse binary data taken from C structures, but I reached the limits of this on a few occasions :

- when my initial structure is padded on a 32 bit acrhitecture, while python is installed on a 64 bit distribution
- when trees of structures are used
- when the structures contains pointers (which is also a problem of 32 vs 64 bits)

So I sometime fetch manually my data, one number after the other `struct.unpack_from('<one element>', ...)` but it is really slow !

What would be the best approach to solve this, given the fact, I'm able to produce a file which contains, for each variables : a name, a type, a size and an offset...

Would it be easy to build a `struct.unpack()`-like function which takes such an arbitrary description ? Or do you have an alternate solution ?

Here is an example of a C code which generate a problematic case :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct {
    uint32_t a;
    uint8_t b;
    float c;
} alpha_T;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t a; 
    int32_t * b;
    double c;
} beta_T;

typedef struct {
    alpha_T a;
    beta_T b;
} gamma_T;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t a_a;
    uint8_t a_b;
    float a_c;
    uint32_t b_a;   
    int32_t * b_b;
    double b_c;

} zeta_T;

int main() {
    gamma_T m;
    size_t p = (size_t) & m;

    printf("m.a.a @%ld\n", (size_t) &(m.a.a) - p);
    printf("m.a.b @%ld\n", (size_t) &(m.a.b) - p);
    printf("m.a.c @%ld\n", (size_t) &(m.a.c) - p);
    printf("m.b.a @%ld\n", (size_t) &(m.b.a) - p);
    printf("m.b.b @%ld\n", (size_t) &(m.b.b) - p);
    printf("m.b.c @%ld\n", (size_t) &(m.b.c) - p);

    zeta_T z;
    size_t n = (size_t) & z;

    printf("z.a_a @%ld\n", (size_t) &(z.a_a) - n);
    printf("z.a_b @%ld\n", (size_t) &(z.a_b) - n);
    printf("z.a_c @%ld\n", (size_t) &(z.a_c) - n);
    printf("z.b_a @%ld\n", (size_t) &(z.b_a) - n);
    printf("z.b_b @%ld\n", (size_t) &(z.b_b) - n);
    printf("z.b_c @%ld\n", (size_t) &(z.b_c) - n);
}
```

The output of this is :

```
m.a.a @0
m.a.b @4
m.a.c @8
m.b.a @16
m.b.b @24
m.b.c @32

z.a_a @0
z.a_b @4
z.a_c @8
z.b_a @12
z.b_b @16
z.b_c @24
```

If I use a plain `struct.Struct('IBfIpd')` I miss the extra padding between `m.a.c` and `m.b.a`, and we can see the difference with the flattened equivalent z.

So my current solution to decode m.b.a, is to prepare the previous table for m (with the type letter) and to use `struct.unpack_from('I', 16, n)`

Comment: Could you provide an example of current solution?

Comment: I added some details... I hope it helps